# Java replace unknown char

Tags: java, json, replace, char

I send text for parsing from my website to my restapi and return the parsing value in a json, but it contains many char look like `\u0000` to `\u0020` and make it crash.

I'll try to replace all non ASCII char and replace the char, but there is too many different (Same display but different value).
[I can't write this char here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZgm1.png)

Comment: Is there a question here? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: It might help of you add some code to your question, and maybe the returned json string.

Comment: You need to fix the problem that causes the text to differ from what you expect, not blindly replacing anything that looks weird.  You have not provided enough information to get help with that.

Comment: Speaking of things that are hard to parse, this question is incomprehensible.

Comment: You need to 1) determine the encoding of the text that's being sent, 2) determine what encoding you're trying to process it as on the other end (they are probably not the same), and 3) find out the code point of that bad character and report that. Showing a picture of an invalid character box doesn't tell anyone much.

Comment: It's in UTF-8, but unknow char are :\u0002\u0000\u0001\u000b\u0004\u0000\u0001\u0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all character `\u0000` to `\u0020` by `&0000;` to `&0020;`

Answer (score 1):

\u0000 is the unicode null character
\u0001 is the unicode "start of heading" character
\u0002 is the unicode "start of text" character
\u0004 is the unicode "end of transmission" character

You can try to extend and override org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.CharacterEscapeHandler to a custom escape handler to replace or get rid of your troublesome chars

Comment: I try to search how to replace all illegal unicode character for all next problems

Comment: Have a look in here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.4.0/JAXB_RI_Extensions/Character_Escape_Handler